# Ajax, Node: Form submits once, then if submit is pressed again, it submits another two times, and continually increments up

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, forms, express

I have a simple form that is written in Pug. Ajax, Node and Express handle the submission and routing of the form.

On the front end, I can submit the form no problem. However, if I press the submit button once again, it then resubmits the form twice, if I press it once more it resubmits it three times (6 total submissions), and will keep incrementing up. I only want it to submit once per click. I don't want to have to reload the page each time....

Feels like I have to clear / reset the ajax query. Any ideas?

**node index.js**

```
router.post('/addalccollection', (req, res, next) => {


 AlcUser.findById(req.session.userId)
 .exec(function (error, user){
   if (error) {
     return next(error);
   } else {


      AlcUser.findOneAndUpdate({email : user.email}, {$push: {alccollections : req.body.alccollectiontitle}}, function(err, alccol) {
        if (err) {
            next(new Error('Cant add'));
        } if (alccol) {

          console.log('Added the collection')
          res.json({success : "Worked Out!", status : 200});
        }

      }) 



    }
  })

});
```

**Ajax Javascript**

```
function addAlcCollectionItem() {

  console.log('add collection');

  $('#addalccollection').submit(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();

       $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         datatype: 'json',

         processData: false,
         data: $("#addalccollection").serialize(),
         url: "/addalccollection",
         success: function(response){
           console.log('Added Collection');
           console.log(response);
        if(response.status == 200){
            //window.location = '/dashboard';
        }


         },

     });

       return false;
  });


}
```

**footer.pug**

```
  form(method='post' style='display: inline-block;' id='addalccollection')

      input#alccollectiontitle.animated(type='text', placeholder='Put Collection Name Here', name='alccollectiontitle', style='')

      input#submitButtonAlcCollection.animated(type='submit', value='Add', onclick='addAlcCollectionItem()')
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't call the addAlcCollectionItem function every time you submit the form?

Answer (score 0):

where is `addAlcCollectionItem` being called from? if it's called more than once it'll bind the form submission multiple times. best is to only call it once, on load. try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#addalccollection').submit(addAlcCollectionItem);
});

function addAlcCollectionItem(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('add collection');
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    datatype: 'json',
    processData: false,
    data: $("#addalccollection").serialize(),
    url: "/addalccollection",
    success: function (response) {
      console.log('Added Collection');
      console.log(response);
      if (response.status == 200) {
        //window.location = '/dashboard';
      }
    }
  });

  return false;
}
```

Comment: Hey there, its being called from a pug file with an onclick. I've added it into an edit above

Comment: heya, the event is being bound every time you click then. try removing it from the onclick with the js above.